# ArrayChecker failure?

Tags: java, arraylist, duplicates

I have a problem with the following code:

```
Import java.util.ArrayList;
public class Car {

private String car;
private Car genCar = new Car();
ArrayList<String> allCars = new ArrayList<>(); 

public void setCar() {
    genCar.setModel();
    genCar.setCreator();
    car = genCar.getModel() + "made by" + genCar.getCreator();
}

public void checkDouble() {

    for (String search : allCars) {
        while (search.equals(car)) {
            setCar();
        }
    }
    allCars.add(car);
}

public void repeater(){
    for(int i = 0; i<52; i++){
        setCar();
        checkDouble();
    }
  }
}
```

Whenever I try to check for duplicates (which this code does) my program still puts the duplicate in the array when I actually try to avoid it this way.

Any solution so this works?

Comment: Hard to tell. What do `setModel()` and `setCreator()` actually do? And your loop **does not search the entire list again**, when you call `setCar()` in the while loop. If the new car you generated is in the list, but not the same as the current value of `search`, it will be added to `allCars`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do this:

```
public void checkDouble() 
{
    for (String search : allCars) 
    {
        while (search.equals(car)) 
        {
            setCar();
        }
    }
    allCars.add(car);
}
```

The problem with this is that, once you found a double, you generate a new car using `setCar()`, **but you do not search the entire list again**.

Do something like:

```
public void avoidDoubles()
{
    while allCars.contains(car)
    {
        setCar(); // generate new, different car
    }
    allCars.add(car);
}
```

FWIW, you might want to change the name of some of the functions. I would call `setCar()` `generateNewCar()` or `newCar()`.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you're trying to do, but in checkDouble you are finding a duplicate and then adding it to the list.

If I understand you correctly, you don't need the loops, All you need to do is to use [ArrayList.contains()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html#contains(java.lang.Object))

```
if(allCars.contains(someString)) 
{
     System.err.println("Duplicate...");
} else 
{    
     //setCar, addCar, etc.    
}
```